# Calling generic functions with multiple bounds?

Tags: kotlin

What is the kotlin equivalent of this Java code?

```
private A typeA;
private B typeB;

public Test(){
  typeA = createType();
  typeB = createType();
}

private <T extends A & B> T createType(){
    return null;
}
```

I tried using the kotlin converter. I am not able to call createType().

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the Kotlin equivalent looks like:

```
private var typeA: A? = null
private var typeB: B? = null

fun test() {
    typeA = createType<C>()
    typeB = createType<C>()
}

private fun <T> createType(): T? where T : A, T : B {
    return null
}

open class A
interface B
class C: A(), B
```

Note that you can have no more than one class in `where` clause, the rest have to be interfaces and that when you call `createType` you need to provide the type parameter that satisfies the bounds (in this case extends `A` and implements `B`)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand the intent from your example, but here is how to express a double upper bound:

```
interface A
interface B

fun <T> createType():T where T : A, T : B {
  return TODO()
}
```

But it is incompatible with your usage example:

```
fun test() {
  val typeA: A = createType()  // error
  val typeB: B = createType()  // error
}
```

How can that even work if `A` is not a sub type of `B`? Maybe there is a more realistic usage example?

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you asked for, but your Java example already can be simplified to:

```
private <T> T createType(){
  return null;
}
```

As your `typeA` and `typeB` are already known, that will work too. 
And that can easily be transformed to the following in Kotlin:

```
fun <T> createType() : T = TODO("implement me")
```

If you give more information on why you really require `T extends A & B` the answers will probably get even better.